# Broken .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm losing my mind here.

I had a .htaccess for a website with the following content:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^XXX.com.ar [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.XXX.com.ar/$1 [r=301,nc] 
</ifmodule>
```

It just added the "www" prior the URL if the user had not written it.

After doing some development, I made a simple "Router" framework for my site. Then, every request had to go to index.php and it "dispatches" it.
So, my .htaccess ended like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^XXX.com.ar [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.XXX.com.ar/$1 [r=301,nc] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
</ifmodule>
```

The problem is that now, when I go to: XXX.com.ar (without the www) I have a 
301 - Moved Permanently

301 - Moved Permanently > 301 - Moved Permanently301 - Moved Permanently

message.

And something like this (in the same document):

ErrorDocument to handle the request.

ErrorDocument to handle the request.> Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error

> was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.ErrorDocument to handle the request.

301 - Moved Permanently ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Quick sanity check, why do you have `[r=301,nc]` in your 1st rewrite rule, specifically "nc" - shouldn't that be `[R=301,L]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the places of the sentences and works well

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^XXX.com.ar [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.XXX.com.ar/$1 [r=301,nc] 
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} XXX.com.ar [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.XXX.com.ar/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work! Gives me a 500 - Internal Server Error. And when the host is reached without the www, it still shows the same error (301)

Comment: I've solved it. Just move the %{HTTP_HOST}... to the bottom. Thanks!